instruction order for prioritization fee
To set prioritization fee, we set 2 instructions:

SetComputeUnitLimit
SetComputeUnitPrice

It seems:



The order of the 2 instructions doesn't matter.




The 2 instructions can be put at beginning or end of the instruction array, doesn't matter.



But, I'm not sure does the order make any difference, can you confirm?
Example tx (devnet):

Put the 2 at beginning: https://solscan.io/tx/2ZMaAaPVrsukSRpe7VC4Jn1VQxtN5XYnbdcNkxmvmwuZ29vnypEe17cnxkFPbb9BpJcc6FK3GwAFsotLzBfRopJc?cluster=devnet
Put the 2 at end:
https://solscan.io/tx/2Y8s921iWwUT1MgQGypPuPw77PHB5arU5zPfjypyecFcFsP6Rf5kNi7hdUCQL31Fjv7G5FTH3ZKZ6btR79TPsZvP?cluster=devnet

